# Java/Android: passing Intent extras from BroadcastReceiver to Activity

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, genymotion

**Update:** Neither eclipse nor the code did cause these trouble. **Genymotion** did.

Maybe my approach is completely wrong, since no one else seems to have this problem - if so, i am open to try different ways rather then fix this problem:
I have the following setting.

A BroadcastReceiver is listening for installations of Apps. Whenever a new App is installed, I create a Notification, using a PendingIntent that is based on a normal Intent via

```
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
```

Before the PendingIntent is created, I put some extras in the normal Intent, that shall be passed to the Activity which is triggered, when the notification is clicked.

```
notificationIntent.putExtra("AppLabel", appLabel); // the installed App
notificationIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("Group", group); // the corresponding group
notificationIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("List", list); // the corresponding list
```

Now this works fine and the notification is displayed. Debugging I can see, that when pIntent is created, all extras are set correctly and passed.
However, when I try to read the extras in the opened Activity trouble starts. I already had to build a workaround, based on an answer here, to read the extras:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
  Object value = bundle.get(key);
  if (key.equals("Group")) {
   group = (ArrayList<String>) value;
  } ... }
```

This also worked for a time, but now i am completely lost. For some Reason, the ArrayList extras are empty [] - the appLabel is still set correctly.

Now the real trouble is, that I am not sure if this is code related, or an eclipse issue.

I observed, that after some deployments, the bundle.keySet() returned different keys then I had set in the putExtra call. I also encounter OutOfSync errors often when I search. Refreshing does help some times, regarding the names of the keys, but the values are lost still.

To anyone who has read this: many thanks! now - has somebody a clue, what is going on here? Does anyone know similar eclipse problems? Or is there an error in the code?
Any proposals for a different design are welcome as well. I'd be just glad, if I can exclude some error sources...
Thanks in advance

Update: Manifest Infos: The launched notification Activity is defined like:

```
<activity
 android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.CompactMenu.Dialog"
 android:label="Notification Receiver"
 android:excludeFromRecents="true">
</activity>
```

The MainActivity however has just a name and a label. Besides:

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="18"
android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

I just added a SystemOut at two points: One when the intent is created by the BCR, one when it is read by the Activity.

```
BroadcastReceiver.getExtras.keyset returns [a,b,c,d]

Activity.getExtras.keyset returns the keys [x,y,z]
```

Searching in all Projects and all Workspace, x,y,z are nowhere to be found... They were used in a previous version of some days ago, so it seems eclipse stored some invalid old data?

Comment: Is your activity's launch mode set as singleTop or singleTask, either in the manifest or with intent flags?

Comment: @matiash The notification Activity is defined like this:
<activity android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.CompactMenu.Dialog"
android:label="Notification Receiver"
android:excludeFromRecents="true">
</activity>

Comment: Sorry, I asked because forgetting to implement `onNewIntent()` is a common mistake for singleTop activities. But it looks like it's not the case.

Comment: I'm getting more and more sure about it being an eclipse problem. I just cant figure what is causing it. Reinstalling the ADT and changing the workspace, i could checkout the app from SVN and it worked for 2 hours. Meanwhile I added and changed some Extras again and boom, now the same issue is back. The activity gets different extras then set in the BCR...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looks like all the technical stuff and all the outOfSync was nasty, but in the end not relevant. 
It just covered a very trivial mistake. The answere can be found here:
[Incorrect extras received with all intents but the first one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517016/incorrect-extras-received-with-all-intents-but-the-first-one)

At least for the current implementation, this looks like solving the problems - except for the sync issues of course but that has not occured again.